# Remove Pdfbox logs

Tags: log4j, pdfbox

How to turn off PDFBox warning logs ?

OR how to solve this issue ?

2018-11-12 17:21:59,665 INFO  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB] To get higher rendering speed on JDK8 or later,
2018-11-12 17:21:59,665 INFO  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB]   use the option -Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider
2018-11-12 17:21:59,665 INFO  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB]   or call System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider")
2018-11-12 17:22:00,095 INFO  [] Pages : 6
2018-11-12 17:22:01,267 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:01,792 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:02,467 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:02,468 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,183 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,184 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,185 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,187 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,187 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,189 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,189 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,190 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,190 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,192 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,192 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,204 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,204 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,435 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,629 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,817 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,817 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,819 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,821 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:04,821 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:05,192 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:05,308 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:05,310 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:05,674 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans' for 'TrebuchetMS'
2018-11-12 17:22:05,701 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans-BoldItalic' for 'Trebuchet-BoldItalic'
2018-11-12 17:22:05,725 WARN  [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont] Using fallback font 'LiberationSans-Bold' for 'TrebuchetMS-Bold'

Comment: You used the log4j label. Please edit to include your log4j config file. Depending on what format you are using, there's a setting to filter the output. Also make sure you're using the latest PDFBox version. I'm surprised that some log messages are duplicated. Are these several PDF files or only one?

Comment: Alternatively, install the TrebuchetMS fonts on your machine.

Comment: Just one pdf file with 6 pages.

Comment: Maybe that file uses multiple instances of the same font.